# How to delete a folder once all files in folder are moved to printer with the vbs script

Tags: shell, printing, vbscript

I tried the following code to print all the files to default printer. But now challenging task is that once files are moved to printer, I have to delete the folder. I tried to delete but files are getting deleted before the all files are moved to printer.

How to check that once the files are moved then only to delete the folder?

```
TargetFolder = "C:\users\asankati\desktop\testsb"

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(TargetFolder)
Set colItems = objFolder.Items

For Each objItem in colItems

    objItem.InvokeVerbEx("print")

Next

strPath = "C:\users\asankati\desktop\testsb"

DeleteFolder strPath

Function DeleteFolder(strFolderPath)
Dim objFSO, objFolder
Set objFSO = CreateObject ("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If objFSO.FolderExists(strFolderPath) Then
    objFSO.DeleteFolder strFolderPath, True
End If
Set objFSO = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the code where I am deleting the folder only when all files are moved to printer.

```
TargetFolder = "C:\users\asankati\desktop\testsb"

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(TargetFolder)

Set colItems = objFolder.Items

Dim  filename 

For Each objItem in colItems
  objItem.InvokeVerbEx("print")
Next

set objFolder = Nothing

Dim objShell

Set objShell = Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

objShell.Run "deletevbs.vbs" 

Set objShell = Nothing
```

Code for deletevbs.vbs:-
Wherein here I am recursively calling the deletefoldere function until file lock error is released.
    strPath = "C:\users\asankati\desktop\testsb"

```
On Error Resume Next

DeleteFolder strPath

DO until err.number = 0 
  DeleteFolder strPath
loop

Function DeleteFolder(strFolderPath)
Dim objFSO, objFolder
Set objFSO = CreateObject ("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If objFSO.FolderExists(strFolderPath) Then
    objFSO.DeleteFolder strFolderPath, True
ELSE
wscript.quit
End If
Set objFSO = Nothing
End Function

on Error GoTo 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a sleep statement before calling the below function. Just keep increasing the sleep time till you achieve your requirement.

```
DeleteFolder strPath
```

Comment: Here requirement is to delete the folder once all the files are moved to printer queue but how do I increase the sleep time till all the files are moved to printer queue, is there any printer status check ???

Comment: Can you suggest a process that checks if the document is finished spolling to the printer?

Comment: Sorry I don't have any idea.